# What is the difference between buffeting and wake galloping?

Tags: aerodynamics, vibration

I am interested in flow-induced vibration and confused between buffeting and wake galloping. As far as I have studied, both phenomena are the vibration of an object with another object in front of it. But I still don't understand what the difference between these two phenomena is.

Thank you

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between buffeting and fluttering?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/50090/19)

Answer (score 1):

"Galloping" seems to be synonymous with the aviation term "flutter", which is a (potentially disasterous) reinforced harmonic oscillation of an aircraft component, such as an aileron.  "Buffeting" is usually applied to a the *felt* effects of *turbulent* airflow on a surface, such as a *pre-stall warning buffet*.

Turbulent flow can be random or rhythmic.  It is the rhythmic pattern, in conjunction with the natural vibrating frequency of the trailing object, that can cause the "flutter".

The "galloping" term seems to be used more frequently in other engineering [pursuits](https://energy.soton.ac.uk/the-multi-mode-response-of-a-cylinder-undergoing-simultaneous-vortex-induced-and-wake-induced-vibrations/), such as power line transmission cables, bridges, and off-shore moorings because the frequency of a very long cable will be much slower than the "buzz" of an aircraft flutter.

Comment: See this [article](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/173085/the-demise-of-the-tacoma-narrows-bridge-was-casused-by-aeroelastic-flutter-but/173216#173216/) on the famous "Galloping" suspension bridge.